# Users page not sorting correctly

Tags: bug, status-norepro, april-fools

## Exhibit 1

I have 51,500 hard-earned rep, but for some reason I'm not showing up as #2 in the users page, sorted by all-time reputation.

[image: Exhibit 1]

## Exhibit 2

Pork-chop sandwiches

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1BDM1oBRJ8

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce any user page with those rep values, obviously you're lying.

Comment: Did you try rebooting?